# Am I allowed to work remotely for a German Company in another EU country in a 90 days framework?

Tags: germany, blue-card, non-citizens

It seems that my question might resemble some already posed, but I'll ask anyway…

I'm a non-EU citizen living in Germany and working for a German Corporation. I'm a EU Blue Card holder with over 24 months legal residence in the country.

Due to certain personal challenges, I'll need to be present in another two EU countries. One is a non-Eurozone and the other is. The total timeframe is up to 90 days.

Would there be any legal or tax implications given that I can stay up to 12 months in another non-EU country without losing status? My residential address will be in Germany during that time, and nothing practically will change.

Answer (score 1):

From Germany’s point of view: Being absent less than 90 days should be no problem. To be on the safe side I’d make sure that the total absence, including normal holidays, is less than 90 days in any one year period, or ask a lawyer with relevant experience.

For the other country, to be legal you’d most likely need a work visa. It would be different if your company sent you to another country to install or repair some machines, but you are working there for yourself, even if it is for your company.

On the other hand, I assume you are just sitting in a hotel room or a relatives home with your computer, so nobody knows you are there working. Again, best to ask a lawyer, who will know what’s the worst that can happen without a work visa. And if it is an acceptable risk to just go there and not let anyone know you’re working there.

Comment: (+1) Actually, you need a permission to work, not a visa, as the German permit already gives you the right to stay in the country. This must typically be obtained separately (and for those who do need a visa, it must be obtained *before* applying for the visa).